# How to claim BTC from address generated with my QR code

Tags: address

How do I claim bitcoins sent to my Wallets address when the receipt generated another address

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes wallets are slow to realise that they have received money. It may be you just need to wait a few minutes or hours.

Key points

- A wallet normally has many addresses, not just one "wallet address". Many wallets have a way to see *all* addresses they have used. This feature may not be prominent, you might need to dig through the menus a bit to find it.
- Bitcoin is never "claimed" in the Bitcoin network. Having provided the sender with an address, the recipient plays no further role in receiving money.  You can receive money while all your devices are turned off. You can receive money even after you destroy all your wallets. By listening for news about confirmed transactions, the wallet can realise that it actually received money a very long time ago.
- Confirmed transactions cannot be undone, cancelled, revoked, reversed, refunded, claimed back, redirected, recovered, invalidated, erased, deleted, altered or otherwise interfered with.

---

Whenever you use the `Receive` button in a current wallet application, it generates a new receiving address. You should not expect to only have one address.

If Bitcoins were sent to an address outside your control there is no way for you to unilaterally claim them and no way to undo, cancel, or reverse the transaction.

The Bitcoin network has no record of who has the private key corresponding to that address. If you know who has the private key, and how to contact them, you could ask that person if they are willing to give you the same amount of money they received.